# How did Bill the Pony survive in "The Lord of the Rings?"

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

On the road to Moria, the Fellowship released Bill the Pony, who in my opinion is the true hero of *The Fellowship of the Ring*. At the end of the series, Sam is reunited with Bill who made his way back to Bree. How on earth did Bill make it back safely to Bree? There were orcs and wargs all over the area. Any theories?

Comment: Not every prey animal in the wild gets eaten immediately, you know. Otherwise there wouldn't be enough survivors to continue the species. Bill's survival for a few months wasn't guaranteed, but shouldn't be all that surprising. Finding his way home is arguably more so, but animals have been known to do that.

Comment: Bill was small, unassuming and presumably cheap, given what we know of his previous owner. My guess is he fit the type of what we in the UK call a "native" pony - one whose recent ancestors lived mostly wild on moors or marginal land, and are well-adapted to local conditions. "Natives" are hardier and have better survival instincts than more highly-bred horses, and can live well on poor grazing, so he'd have a good chance to start with. Gandalf's "words" presumably gave him extra protection from orcs etc.

Comment: Also there's likely some boring zoological explanation... would wolves actually hunt ponies in a biome where they co-exist? Generally predators avoid hunting any animal dangerous enough that might wound them while hunting it and horses definitely qualify given that they kick like a... horse. And it will very likely outpace wolves out in the open. Also truly natural wolves without supernatural influence would smell human/hobbit on Bill for quite a while and avoid him for that reason.

Comment: @Amarth Kicky/Stampy animals do tend to beat biting animals in a fight due to attacking with a less vulnerable part of their body.

Comment: Eru wanted him to.

Answer (score 65):

According to [the wiki](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Bill):

> ... Gandalf had previously spoken to Bill, "words of guard and guiding," reminding him of what he had learned in Rivendell and advising him to go where there was grass and at last return to Elrond's place or wherever he wished to go.

....

> He laid his hand on the pony’s head, and spoke in a low voice. ‘Go with words of guard and guiding on you,’ he said. ‘You are a wise beast, and have learned much in Rivendell. Make your ways to places where you can find grass, and so come in time to Elrond’s house, or wherever you wish to go.
>
> ‘There, Sam! He will have quite as much chance of escaping wolves and getting home as we have.’

So yes, in a very real sense, [A Wizard Did It](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AWizardDidIt).

Comment: That last quote... I don't like those odds lol

Comment: @DKNguyen Well, 7 of 9 of them made it home, minus one finger.  8 if you count divine intervention for Gandalf...

Comment: @KevinRubin That's with the advantage of not having uncertainty though lol

Comment: I have always thought that this is a good example of Tolkien's view of "magic" and how it connects with his "religious" ideas. There is no instant "salvation" for Bill. He has to find his own way.

Comment: And Boromir did escape the wolves....